# WebStart keeps trying to use Java 1.4 when I have Java 1.6 installed

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am having an issue where I have Java 1.5 and 1.6 installed but when I try to open a specific webstart app, it keeps trying to use Java 1.4. I have tried uninstalling Java 1.4 but when I try to open it, it just reinstalls Java 1.4 and tries to use that again. It is using Java Web Start. I don't know why this is happening. I have used websites to check which version of Java is running on my machine, I have checked in the command prompt, and I have also checked in the browser settings. I have checked my environment variables and my JAVA_HOME variable and PATH variable are both pointing to Java 1.5.

Does anyone know what the issue may be or anything else I could try to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Also forgot to mention, I looked at the jnlp file the web app is using and it has the following: <j2se version="1.5*" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"... which means it should be trying to use java 1.5.

Comment: Try validating the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  If the input file is invalid, it is anyone's guess as to how a JWS client will interpret it.

Comment: From the doc it seems that just `version="1.5+"` would be supported, not `version="1.5*"`, can you change that?

Comment: Also note that in Java 6 the `<j2se>` seems to have been renamed to `<java>`, altough the spec sais you can use both. Might there be `<java>` element, too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the JNLP-file explicitly requesting Java 1.4, and you need to alter it in order to fix this.

A simple fix, that may be usable, is to change the "1.4" string for the requested version to "1.4+" which will pick any later version if 1.4 is not available.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. No where in the jnlp file is Java 1.4 mentioned. As originally commented on my post, I showed an extract of the jnlp file which is actually looking for Java 1.5, hence my issue. The app won't open for me because it is trying to use java 1.4.

Comment: This is the usual reason for it.   Please add any additional information you can provide to your question, as it may prove to be important.